# WinMerge - disable comparison

Tags: winmerge

Is there a way I can remove the orange comparison between 2 side-by-side (untitled) files such that they are both just regular black-and-white text?

Basically, sometimes I paste 2 blobs of text in WinMerge real quick, but I want to go back and tweak them and re-compare, but it's hard to "tweak" and edit the text when there are orange and gray blocks everywhere..

Comment: Copy the text out into a text editor, edit and return.  Its kinda asking a lot of an app to configure it to not do its primary function.

Comment: @heavyd Yeah, just wondering if anyone else knows something I don't. It doesn't help that I'm still basically a noob when it comes to merging anyway . Those orange and gray blocks and carets everywhere start to look more like a work of art than code..... The colors Duke, the colors!...